# How to know which instruction taking the longest time to finish ? (to increase my program performance)

Tags: c#

I need to know how can I get every instruction's duration so I can maintain the code to increase the performance of my program .

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2008 ...

Comment: There are several versions of Visual Studio 2008 with different options included. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Editions for details

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help Brian , frankly I don't know what profiler is ,but I'll search to lean how to use it .

Comment: By the way...I'm using VS2008 Professional edition

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a profiler. If you have Visual Studio Team System, there's one included. Otherwise take a look at [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm?gclid=CLfco-GK8ZwCFZCB3godfXzhjQ) or [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).

Answer (score 2):

what you're looking for is a profiler I believe :)

see: [Profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiler_%28computer_science%29) and [List of Performance Analysis Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)

Answer (score 1):

You want an application profiler for that, it shows exactly what code takes how long.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a profiler to accomplish this. It exists several profilers, some are free.

My preference goes to [Red Gate Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you should go upto level of instructions to measure performance bottlenecks. Micro optimization can be harmful. You should go up to function profiling. If you are using VS2005 or 2008 you can use

1. Performance wizard
2. CLR profiler

to profile your functions.

Alternatly I personally recomend using [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Since Ants and dotTrace are very good but commercial tools (I wouldn't call them expensive - they're worth the money), I recently heard about the [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler), which is free of charge. Did not try it because of lack of time, but maybe you want to give it a try.

(no, I am not affiliated with them)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application running and you want to improve its performance using a profiler (.net or database) is a must .DotTrace and Ants are famous ones for good reasons.

If you are using SQL Server ,SQL server profiler is a great tool to trace and watch what's going on ,on the server side of your application.

If you want to decide what approach is better to use you can use ILDASM to disassemble your code to IL and see what's going on under the hood Although it's not a simple task but I think it worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx) as well, might give you some more *vauge* hints as to what could be improved. (Oh, and it's free!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one have mentioned this yet, but if you want to know the cost of individual instructions, look them up [here](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) or [here](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/Pages/default.aspx).

The cost of individual instructions varies between CPU's, but both AMD and Intel (and any other CPU maker) documents this.

The problem is that determining the cost of instructions is not straightforward. You have a lot of metrics to consider: There's the latency, whether it is pipelined (fully or partially), how big the instruction is (affects instruction cache) and so on. So this information is only really helpful if you're writing a single *really* performance-sensitive function where you're either writing assembly yourself, or closely reading the compiler-generated ASM to find and eliminate inefficiencies. And if you know a fair bit about how the CPU works.

But before you get to this point, you should use a profiler as everyone else have suggested. That helps you narrow down where the time is being spent, and what needs optimizing.